# Show that $\int^*|(f_n)|d\lambda\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$. But $f_n(x)$ doesn't converge pointwise $\forall x$.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Here $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. Furthermore:
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x)=1_{[0,1]}(2^m x-j)
\end{equation*}
Where $n=2^m+j,\ 0\leq j\leq 2^m-1$. Prove that $\lim_n \int^* |f_n|d\lambda\to 0$ and that $f_n(x)$ doesn't converge pointwise for any $x\in [0,1]$.

The second part isn't that difficult and not of too much interest. I am rather interested in the first part. My go-to approach would be to define a new function that does the same for $x\in [0,1]$ and from there we draw a line to zero. This would then be a function which is continuous with compact support. This means that the Lebesgue-Integral would simply be the Riemann Integral.

Let us call this function $\phi_n$. The problem I run into, however, is that
\begin{equation*}
\int^* |f_n|d\lambda=\int^*\lim_n \phi_nd\lambda=\int_0^1 |2^mx-j|=|2^{m-1}-j|
\end{equation*}
And thus we get:
\begin{equation*}
\int^*\lim_n |f_n|d\lambda=\lim_n |2^{m-1}-j|\not\to 0
\end{equation*}
What is going on? I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: If for all $x \in [0,1]$ the sequence $(f_n(x))$ does not converges then what is $\lim_n|f_n|$?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say. I am asking about $\lim \int^* |f_n|$ -- not $\lim_n |f_n|$. Or is there something I don't see?

Comment: I am sorry I thought you were trying to compute the integral of the limit of the $(f_n)$ in your last computation. What is $\int^*$? Is it the Lebesgue integral over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: It is the upper integral with respect to the Lebesgue measure in this case. Yes. I will edit my post appropriately

Comment: I get $\int_0^1 |2^mx-j|\, dx = 2^{m-1} - j + j^2 2^{1-m}$.

Comment: For $n\to \infty$ the right summand converges to zero though and you are left with my weird expression, right? Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $2^m \leq n < 2^{m+1}$, $m = \lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor$, $j = n-2^m$,
$$
f_n(x) = 1_{[0,1]}(2^{\lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor}x - n + 2^{\lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor}),
$$
and $f_n(x) = 1$ if and only if $0 \leq 2^{\lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor}x - n + 2^{\lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor} \leq 1$ which is equivalent to
$$
\frac{n - 2^{\lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor}}{2^{\lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor}} \leq x \leq \frac{n - 2^{\lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor} + 1}{2^{\lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor}}.
$$
Thus
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} f_n(x) dx = \frac{ 1}{2^{\lfloor \ln_2(n) \rfloor}} \rightarrow 0.
$$

Comment: I have only now realized that you were correct all along: I interpreted the task as $1_{[0,1]}(x)\cdot (2^mx-j)$ which obviously didn't fulfill the requirements. However, your interpretation is the only valid one.